# Rewrite root domain to different path then subdomain with web.config

Tags: azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I think this should be a quite easy task, but I somehow struggle on it.

What i want to do:

```
mydomain.ch -> should redirect to a simple html page in folder public
demo.mydomain.ch -> should redirect to a angular application
demo.mydomain.ch/api -> is the backend (express.js) for the angular application
```

My folder/file structure

```
web.config
demo
-> simplepage.html
-> index.html
-> angular.js
-> ...
backend
-> server.js
```

Here my current ruleset:

```
<rule name="mydomain.ch rule"  stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^mydomain\.ch$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="demo/simplepage.html"/>
</rule>

<rule name="Root rule">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="demo/index.html"/>
</rule>

<!-- For static files, redirect to the URI -->
<rule name="Static files">
    <action type="Rewrite" url="demo{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>

<!-- For Express.js middleware API, if using api/ prefix, then use server.js -->
<rule name="Express.js URIs">
    <match url="api/*"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="backend/server.js"/>
</rule>

<!-- For Angular.js URIs, rewrite to the index.html file -->
<rule name="Angular">
    <match url=".*"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="demo/index.html"/>
</rule>
```

What currently happens is, that every call to mydomain.ch or demo.mydomain.ch is redirected to the angular app. What do I have to change to redirect the mydomain.ch to simplepage.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you change the rule to something like this:

```
<rule name="mydomain.ch rule"  stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" /> 
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\.ch$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="demo/simplepage.html"/>
</rule>
```